# Show that $Σ(E_1) = Σ(E_2)$.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $E_1$, $E_2$ be two collections of subsets of the non-empty $X$. If $E_1\subset E_2\subset Σ(E_1)$, prove that $Σ(E_1) = Σ(E_2)$.

Where, $E$ be an arbitrary collection of subsets of $X$. The intersection of all $σ$-algebras of subsets of $X$ which include $E$ is called the $σ$-algebra generated by $E$ and it is denoted by $Σ(E)$. Can give me any hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\Sigma\Sigma(E)=\Sigma(E)$ and, of course, that $\Sigma$ is a weakly increasing function with respect to set inclusion.